# Is there a set of daily reminders and daily reflections one can contemplate on?

Tags: lay-buddhism, right-intention

I am trying have a routine and life style that help me learn and practice dharma. I came across videos on YouTube where a monk from Thailand talked about evening routines, daily reminders etc. which are practiced at the monastery.

> 10 daily reminders: https://youtu.be/RoZA9mWoukA

> A Day in the Life of a Buddhist Monk: https://youtu.be/PlsaqLddfws

I wanted to know are there any particular set of daily reminders and daily reflections I can use. Have anyone used something like these in their practice?

Comment: Just pick your favorite verse from Sutras for your contemplation. Practice Metta and Anapanasati on a daily basis.

Answer (score 3):

I use chanting and contemplations like...

> This body is relentlessly aging...now!
> The body’s health is temporary.
> It will decline, sicken and die.
> The dying process is happening.
> Everything I value and consider mine will
> eventually become separated from me.
> I ‘own’ my actions.
> Whatever actions I shall do,
> for good or for ill,
> of that I will be the heir.

and, Eight Verses for Training the Mind

> With the desire and resolve to attain enlightenment for the welfare of all living beings, may I always cherish them
>
> Each moment may I humbly practice loving-friendliness.
>
> Being constantly mindful, the moment a disturbing emotion or negative attitude arises, I intend to drop it.
>
> Whenever I meet those overwhelmed by suffering, may I cherish and care for them as a treasure.
>
> Whenever others, because of jealousy, treat me badly, with abuse, insult, slander, or in other unjust ways, may I accept this defeat, and offer the victory to others.
>
> When someone whom I have benefited or in whom I have placed trust and hope, treats me in hurtful ways without reason, may I see that person as my precious teacher.
>
> May I offer both directly and indirectly all help, happiness and benefit to all beings, my mothers, and may I take upon myself, all of their harmful actions, pain, and suffering.
>
> May I keep all of these practices undefiled by stains of the eight worldly concerns.
> [gain and loss, pleasure and pain
> praise and blame, fame and dishonor]
> and by recognizing the emptiness and illusory nature of all existing things,
> may I liberate myself from the bondage of attachment
> and mistaken views of reality.

Composed by the Buddhist Master Langri Tangpa (1054-1123), Eight Verses for Training the Mind is a highly revered text from the Mahayana Lojong (mind training) tradition.

and the Charnal Ground Contemplations (on body impermanence);
the Four Vows...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Theravada version:

Please refer to "[A Chanting Guide](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0000.html)" by The Dhammayut Order in the USA.

It has everything you need, and too much more.

From here, I would shortlist:

- [Homage to the Buddha, Three Refuges and Five Precepts](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0064.html)
- [Five Subjects for Frequent Recollection](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0007.html)
- [The Four Dhamma Summaries](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0013.html)
- [The Three Characteristics](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0043.html)
- [The Sublime Attitudes](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0015.html)
- [Short Reminder from the Mahaparinibbana Sutta](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0095.html)

If you plan to actually recite in Pali, I would suggest to look at the [Pronunciation Guide](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0003.html).

Comment: This is a good list. But I would remove the seven step breath meditation. That's Ajahn Lee's instructions and they are quite different than what you find in the suttas. For example, the suttas never say inhale through the spine. A second reason to remove it is because there's no need to recite instructions. You learn the instructions then you do them.

Comment: @triplej Thanks. I have removed the breath meditation steps since they are neither a reflection nor a recitation per se.

Answer (score 1):

“I take refuge in the Buddhas, I take refuge in the Dharmas, I take refuge in the Sanghas”

These are the daily reminders.